# How to pass pdf file to UIActivityController?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

So far I have created a pdf file. It is true, because my function get inside conditional:

```
var objects: [AnyObject] = [string, url, image]
if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(pdfPath) {
    let data = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(pdfPath)
    objects.append(data) //it gets here
}
```

Then I pass it as:

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objects, applicationActivities: nil)
presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Finally there is no `iBooks` or any other app that can read pdf files. Why?